# Use value of one column as identifier in another table in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: sql

I have two table one of which contains the rule for another

```
create table t1(id int, query string)
create table t2(id int, place string)

insert into t1 values (1,'id < 10')
insert into t1 values (2,'id == 10')
```

And the values in t2 are

```
insert into t2 values (11,'Nevada')
insert into t2 values (20,'Texas')
insert into t2 values (10,'Arizona')
insert into t2 values (2,'Abegal')
```

I need to select from second table as per the value of first table column value.

like

```
select * from t2 where {query}
```

or

```
with x(query)
as
(select c2 from test)
select * from test where query;
```

but neither are helping.

Comment: This requires dynamic SQL.  I wonder if there is a better way to encode your possible conditions rather than using a string (such as ranged for each column).

Comment: You need to look up "dynamic SQL", but it is generally dangerous and there is usually a better way that avoids potential SQL injection. The exact command depends on which RDMS you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, however any dynamic query example would be of great help

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using snowflake, and adding trouble to problem just get to know snowflake don't support dynamic query. Now using python client to pass on the value

Comment: I wrote the python script and tested. finally it working I have post my resolution below.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with storing criteria in a table like this:

- First, as has already been noted, you'll likely have to resort to dynamic SQL, which can get messy, and limits how you can use it.
- It's going to be problematic (to say the least) to validate and parse your criteria. What if someone writes a rule of `[id] *= 10`, or `[this_field_doesn't_exist] = blah`?

If you're just storing potential values for your [id] column, one solution would be to have your `t1` (storing your queries) include a *min value* and *max value*, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
    [id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    min_value INT NULL, 
    max_value INT NULL
)
```

Note that both the min and max values can be null. Your provided criteria would then be expressed as this:

```
INSERT INTO t1
([id], min_value, max_value)
VALUES
(1, NULL, 10),
(2, 10, 10)
```

Note that I've explicitly referenced what attibutes we're inserting into, as you should also be doing (to prevent issues with attributes being added/modified down the line).

A null value on `min_value` means no lower limit; a null `max_value` means no upper limit.

To then get results from `t2` that meet all your `t1` criteria, simply do an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t2.* 
FROM t2
    INNER JOIN t1 ON
        (t2.id <= t1.max_value OR t1.max_value IS NULL)
        AND
        (t2.id >= t1.min_value OR t1.min_value IS NULL)
```

Note that, as I said, this will only return results that match *all* your criteria. If you need to more complex logic (for example, show records that meet Rules 1, 2 *and* 3, *or* meet Rule 4), you'll likely have to resort to dynamic SQL (or at the very least some ugly JOINs).

---

As stated in a comment, however, you want to have more complex rules, which might mean you have to end up using dynamic SQL. *However*, you still have the problem of validating and parsing your rule. How do you handle cases where a user enters an invalid rule?

A better solution might be to store your rules in a format that can easily be parsed and validated. For example, come up with an XML schema that defines a valid rule/criterion. Then, your `Rules` table would have a `rule` XML attribute, tied to that schema, so users could only enter valid rules. You could then either shred that XML document, or create the SQL client-side to come up with your query.

Comment: I am sorry but min and max are out of question, as the c2 in test can have any rule.like it may contain another column as well. could you please give an example of how to use dynamic query in this scenario

Comment: Hmm. Then you might be stuck with dynamic SQL. Another possibility: Use JSON or XML to encode your rules (e.g. it might be easier to develop an XML schema that defines what types of rules you can use). Then, you could shred the XML (or create SQL from the XML client-side) to come up with the query you need.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer myself. And I am putting it below.
I have used python CLI to do the job. (As snowflake does not support dynamic query)
I believe one can use the same for other DB (tedious but doable)

setting up configuration to connect

```
CONFIG_PATH = "/root/config/snowflake.json"

with open(CONFIG_PATH) as f:
     config = json.load(f)


#snowflake
snf_user = config['snowflake']['user']
snf_pwd = config['snowflake']['pwd']
snf_account = config['snowflake']['account']
snf_region = config['snowflake']['region']
snf_role = config['snowflake']['role']


ctx = snowflake.connector.connect(
      user=snf_user,
      password=snf_pwd,
      account=snf_account,
      region=snf_region,
      role=snf_role
)
```

--comment
Used multiple cursor as in loop we don't want recursive connection

```
cs = ctx.cursor()
cs1 = ctx.cursor()
query = "select c2 from test"
cs.execute(query)
for (x) in cs:
     y = "select * from test1 where {0}".format(', '.join(x).replace("'",""))
          cs1.execute(y)
          for (y1) in cs1:
               print('{0}'.format(y1))
```

And boom done